# How to parse .proto file and read custom message options using protobuf-net.Reflection?

Tags: protobuf-net

I am parsing a set of proto files using FileDescriptorSet. Now I need to read a custom message option applied to a message in the set. How can I do that?

My proto could look like this:

```
syntax = "proto3";
import "google/protobuf/descriptor.proto";

extend google.protobuf.MessageOptions {
  string my_option = 51234;
}

message Country {
    string code = 1;
    option (my_option) = "true";
}
```

When I read DescriptorProto for the Country message, the DescriptorProto.Options contains no UninterpretedOptions or similar that could be my option...?

And a bonus question: How can I read the message/field comments in proto files?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Found a way to do this but not sure if best way:

```
DescriptorProto message = ...
bool isMyBoolOptionSet = message.Options != null && Extensible.GetValue<bool>(message.Options, [tag of option as declared in proto file]);
```

Comment: This, basically. This is pretty much how the tool parses custom options internally.

Comment: not currently, no; I started a branch on that ages ago that tracked them, but it never hit completion; it isn't technically all that *hard*, it just needs effort